# User Input Batch File

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

I am very new with coding. I am trying to create a batch file that will ask the user if he/she is sure about turning the PC off. This is what I have:

```
@echo off

set /p min=Enter the minutes for the computer shutdown or press enter to cancel? 
set /a min=%min%*60

set /p response=Are you sure[Y/N]? 

if response==Y or y goto timer

if response==N or n goto cancel

:timer

shutdown /r /t %min%

:cancel

exit
```

However, even if I press no, the script programs the shutdown. Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: For a case insensitibe comparison use `If /I "response"=="Y"` also for a Y/N answer use `Choice` on it's own, it will only accept a case insensitive Y or N answer; `N` will be an error level of `2`, `Y` will be an error level of `1`

Comment: I used the choice command. Thank you